# How to avoid divergent branch in simple if statements in Cuda

Tags: c, cuda

I am wondering, how can anyone avoid branching in kernels when the threads have to compare and store values either from local, shared or global variables. For example the following code checks a shared variable and sets a `bool` flag to true accordingly

```
if ( shared_variable < local_value ){
    shared_bool_var = true;
}
__syncthreads();
```

The problem  here is that all threads access the same variable and all will overwrite to true.
So i would use a threadId.x check to only let one thread access that variable but this would cause branch divergence.

```
if ( threadIdx.x == 0 && shared_variable < local_value ){
    shared_bool_var = true;
}
__syncthreads();
```

The question here is what should I prefer to do? In both cases it seems safe since the syncthread will protect from *Hazards* (read before write etc). My preference is the second solution but usually the code is not that simple.

In the aforementioned case, is it safe to allow all threads to access 1 shared memory location or this would cause a bank conflict or serialization of memory access?
Thanks

Comment: There's no divergence here, there is no `else`. I'm not sure what happens if all threads write the same value to the same location, I don't think there is any kind of "write collapsing", but I could be wrong. So maybe it'll be serialized, maybe it won't. Not sure this is documented. But the stored value will be correct anyway. However from your code it seems that `VALUE` is a shared variable too, so why bother making `shared_bool_var` shared? After all, all threads will evaluate the condition identically.

Comment: @Cicada Suppose that shared_bool_var is variable that affects all threads within a block.

Comment: @Cicada My bad, I forgot to mention that the `local_value` is per thread dependent. I ve corrected the question. A whole block may not have any thread to set this `shared_bool_var` to `true` so it needs to be checked.

Comment: Try a reduction where each thread checks two booleans into single one at each iteration until there is only one left.

Comment: I have tested the simple code reported [here](http://pastebin.com/jWzLbQAh). The two kernels have very similar performance, in terms of branch efficiency, which is `100%` as noted by @Cicada, and of issued instructions. I do not see a concrete reason to prefer the second to the first, apart from the cleanliness.

Comment: @JackOLantern Well thats why I believe that avoiding branching at all cost is not a panacea. Its just that someone has to weight the trade-offs of mem-access for example vs divergence. Too many factors to consider when it comes to cuda performance. Also, is it considered a branch when some threads execute an instruction while others dont execute anything? I mean, its surely different than executing different instructions isnt it?

Comment: The advice is not to avoid branching, it's to avoid *intra-warp divergence*. Performance problems arise when there are many combinatorial branches unequally taken by threads *within a warp* and/or each branch takes many cycles to complete. Here, the code you posted *does not* exhibit any kind of divergence: the branch has *only one* alternative (no `else`), so it really doesn't matter: you are not losing any cycle (the `if` body has to execute anyway!). Inter-warp divergence is also completely harmless.

Comment: The title of your post is misleading, as pointed out by @Cicada . There is no branch divergence.

Comment: @JackOLantern well why does the Nvidia visual profiler marks as divergent branch the second code? Is it just misleading?

Comment: Possibly because your first code always evaluates identically across a warp (hence no "divergence"). The point being that you are not losing any cycle (except for the `threadIdx` comparison) with the second code over the first one. If you still have doubts, benchmark it.

Comment: @Cicada If you want you can answer the question with more details so I can accept it and close the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important thing to note: semantically and functionally speaking, both code stanzas are not equivalent:

```
// set var to true if ANY thread in the block verifies the predicate
if (shared_variable < local_value) {
    shared_bool_var = true;
}

// set var to true if THE FIRST thread in the block verifies the predicate
if (threadIdx.x == 0 && shared_variable < local_value) {
    shared_bool_var = true;
}
```

But back to your question:

> In the aforementioned case, is it safe to allow all threads to access 1 shared memory location or this would cause a bank conflict or serialization of memory access?

After verification in the [CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html), it seems there is some kind of write-collapsing mechanism that prevents serialization of write-accesses to the same address: instead, only one thread writes its value (but which thread is undefined).

**[CC 1.x:](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-1-x)**

> If a non-atomic instruction executed by a warp writes to the same location in shared memory for more than one of the threads of the warp, only one thread per half-warp performs a write and which thread performs the final write is undefined.

**[CC 2.x and above:](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-2-x)**

> A shared memory request for a warp does not generate a bank conflict between two threads that access any address within the same 32-bit word (even though the two addresses fall in the same bank): In that case, [...] for write accesses, each address is written by only one of the threads (which thread performs the write is undefined).

Additionally:

> So i would use a threadId.x check to only let one thread access that variable but this would cause branch divergence.

This isn't "more divergent" than the first code. The first stanza exhibits divergence whenever a whole warp doesn't evaluate the predicate identically. The second stanza exhibits divergence only in the first warp of every block. In both cases, none of these branches have an impact on performance: there is no `else` body and the `if` body is a single instruction.